# Modifying body tag in Oracle

Tags: tags, apex, ng-app

Is there a way to edit the `<body>` tag in Apex 4.1 and make it display the following:

`<body ng-app="app">` ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Application you are working on
2. Go to Shared Components->Themes->Create/Edit
3. Under "Component Defaults->Page" write down which template is being used for the Page Template
4. Go to Shared Components->Templates->Click on the name of the page you wrote down in Step 3 above
5. Under "Body", replace `#ONLOAD#` with `ng-app="app"`
6. Click "Apply Changes"
7. Go back to the Application page and click "Run Application"
8. View the page in your web browser
9. View source and you will see `<body ng-app="app">`